# Objeto no localizado php ajax xampp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Tengo un problema con mandar una variable por `AJAX` en `php` 
he intentado de todo lo que se me ha ocurrido,  al inicio pensaba que era la dirección de mi archivo `php` le puse `./prueba.php`, `prueba.php`, `/prueba.php` y nada, también chequeé el nombre las variables que intento obtener pero está bien, estoy comenzando a creer que es **XAMPP** pero es muy pero muy poco probable

Este es mi código, es un código simple pero no entiendo por qué no sirve

```
function prueba(){
    console.log("hola")
    $.ajax({
        url :"prueba.php",
        data : "'data'='1';",
        type :"POST",
        sucess: function(datos){
        console.log(datos)
        },
    error : function(e){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
    });
}
```

Esta función se activa al darle click a un botón con el evento `onclick;`
Este es mi código de `php` intenté quitar todo para ver dónde estaba el error pero aun así no lo encontré

`prueba.php`

```
<?php 
$pruebas = $_POST['data'];
return $pruebas;
?>
```

Mi archivo `js` y el `php` están en la misma carpeta.

Comment: Intenta mandar esto en el data: `{'data':'1'}`

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo, pueden ser dos factores, el primero es como estás mandando los datos en el `ajax`, la mejor opción que he visto para mandarlos es la siguiente:

`AJAX JQUERY`

```
function prueba(){
var datos = {
    'data' : 1 //Variable de tipo json, le das el nombre y el valor al dato que vas a mandar y así mismo los pones sí vas a enviar más
};
$.ajax({
    url :"prueba.php",
    data : datos,
    type :"POST",
    sucess: function(datos){
        console.log(datos)
    },
    error : function(e){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
    }
});
```

Y lo segundo sería como estás respondiendo en el `php`

```
<?php 
$pruebas = $_POST['data'];
echo $pruebas; //Ajax recibe son los resultados que se imprimen o se muestran, por lo que un return no hace eso
?>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!